# Does system.describe is still in JSON-RPC spec

Tags: specifications, json-rpc

I have json-rpc librarary written in php and I use it in javascript in other project (but it can use other library), I look into a spec and in [1.0](http://json-rpc.org/wiki/specification) there is not `system.describe`. It's defined in [historical 1.1](http://jsonrpc.org/historical/json-rpc-1-1-alt.html) but not in [2.0](http://www.jsonrpc.org/specification). Does it mean that it's drop from specification? Was there any discussion about it?

Comment: Most users seem to be pretty happy that JSON-RPC isn't evolving into an all-encompassing ball of hair like SOAP did. As `system.describe` is simply an RPC call like any other, it needn't be in the RPC spec itself. The spec says that "reserved" names should be of the form `rpc.*`. I'll leave you to ponder the interlocking implications of those two statements.

Comment: @David-SkyMesh But 1.1 spec say that `system.describe` is not ordinary method it return different result. I seen `rpc.*` and spec say that extensions are in it's own specs but I don't see them anywhere.

Comment: Yes, that's the 1.1 spec *proposals*. You'll note that there's nothing in the 2.0 spec (proper).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are free to use *"system.describe"* as any other usual method name, in JSON-RPC 2.0.

If (and only if) it is for local standardization purposes, you can to use the prefix method name `rpc.` (ex. "rpc.system.describe"), see [Extensions section](http://www.jsonrpc.org/specification#extensions),

> Each system extension is defined in a related specification. All system extensions are OPTIONAL

Help yourself, about "defined in a related specification", you not need an international discussion or consensus, it is also for local/personal use.

This kind of "local standardization" is interesting in a context of multiple endpoints (or many local web-services), and some common and controlled options to check endpoints.

---

### Notes

Another question is about JSON-RPC 2.0 itself... [2.0 specification](http://www.jsonrpc.org/specification) is alive? It is [RESTful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer)-compatible? How many systems are using it, there are some statistical data?  ... I am using it, but with this kind of questions :-)

Uniform interface, with self-descriptive messages, is a good requirement, that can enhance JSON-RPC pack (eg. by use of [JSON-LD](http://json-ld.org)), but there are no discussion since 2013 (perhaps 2010).